# How can make simpler this "IF"-condition

Tags: php

```php
$regionFilter = isset($additionalDate['region']) &&
    in_array($additionalDate['region'], $this->request["insuranceCompanyRegion"]);

$cityFilter =  isset($additionalDate['city']) &&
    in_array($additionalDate['city'], $this->request["insuranceCompanyCity"]);

if ($isRegionFilter && $isCityFilter) {
    $filterCondition = $regionFilter && $cityFilter;
} elseif ($isCityFilter) {
    $filterCondition = $cityFilter;
} elseif ($isRegionFilter) {
    $filterCondition = $regionFilter;
}
if ($filterCondition) {
    $this->companyIds[$q->id] = $q->name;
}
```

I need to make this condition simpler to edit in the future, how can I make it?

Comment: If I have the both variables true I need to check both conditions $regionFilter and $cityFilter, tho if I have only one of them true then I need to check only this condition

Comment: $filterCondition=($isRegionFilter && $isCityFilter) ? $regionFilter && $cityFilter : (($isRegionFilter) ? $regionFilter : $cityFilter);

Answer (score 3):

```
if ($regionFilter || $cityFilter) { 
    $this->companyIds[$q->id] = $q->name;
}
```

Comment: I think this is the answer @daniil-petrenko.

Comment: Exactly, cause if $filterCondition is set you only have 2 ways ( true or false ).

if ( $filterCondition ) {
    $this->companyIds[$q->id] = $q->name;
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use shorthand If / Else check this [1](https://davidwalsh.name/php-ternary-examples)
so for example

```
if($isRegionFilter && $isCityFilter){
            $filterCondition = $regionFilter && $cityFilter;
```

becomes

```
$filterCondition=($isRegionFilter && $isCityFilter) ? $regionFilter && $cityFilter;
```

Comment: For reference, this kind of operator is called a "ternary" or "conditional" operator.

Answer (score 0):

```
$filterCondition=($isRegionFilter && $isCityFilter) ? $regionFilter && $cityFilter : (($isRegionFilter) ? $regionFilter : $cityFilter);
```

Comment: don't use multiple ternaries in one statement; that is way harder to read and understand than your actual code from your question ... the problem is everything you are doing is unneeded since you are only dealing with boolean logic in your example code